# kadane algorithm - any order constraints on input?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, kadanes-algorithm

I apologize if I have missed some assumption about the input but doesn't this algorithm fail for input like **{2, -3, 1}** ?

When processing **-3**, the currentSum gets **2+ (-3) = -1** and currentStartIndex starts anew!
Am I overlooking something obvious?

http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Kadane%27s_Algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't - in this case, since the sum is now `-1`, it gets reset - which you realized.

But, prior to the reset, in the previous index, the max is saved as the value - `2` - at that time, since it is larger than `0`, the previous max.

```
if currentMaxSum > maxSum then
            (maxSum, maxStartIndex, maxEndIndex) := (currentMaxSum, currentStartIndex, currentEndIndex)
endif
```

So in the end the algorithm will give you `2`, which is the max.

This algorithm only has one issue, which is that in the case that all elements are negative it will give you `0` which means the best is an empty array. The correctness of this answer depends on if you allow empty arrays.

Comment: damn..some mornings, even two mugs of coffee ain't enough!
Thanks Ziyao! :)